# Change background of html tag itself

Tags: javascript, css

How to change background for this tag?

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="full" lang="en">
```

**JS**

```
    window.onload = function () {
       var fileNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
       var imgContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("full");

   // It does not work...    
  imgContainer.style.background = "url('../images/' + fileNumber + '.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.full {
    background: url('../images/5.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you need to use:

```
imgContainer[0].style.background = "url('../images/" + fileNumber + ".jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
```

Comment: Your background string isn't concatenated properly either. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using the [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function which can return an array of elements, so you'll need to specify the exact index that you want to update :

```
imgContainer[0].style.background = 'url("../images/' + fileNumber + '.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed';
```

Or since you are targeting the `html` element directly, you could probably use [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/documentElement) which should point to it :

```
document.documentElement.style.background = 'url("../images/' + fileNumber + '.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed';
```